# How do it make the mobile nav close when clicking outside the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using this to close my nav but, this only works when I click a span or at tag. What do I need to add if I want to close the nav outside of the menu https://gyazo.com/d31c66ec5dc021a69d9781d5df279c1f underneath the menu.

Current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-toggle"><a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".inner-navigation"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.inner-navigation.show, body', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).is('a, span')  && !$(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('menu-item-has-children') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is the html code:

<div class="nav-toggle"><a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".inner-navigation"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
                </div>

Comment: where is the HTML code? This is the JS or being specific jQuery code.

Comment: Don't add the HTML code in comment. Edit your question and add HTML code there itself.

Comment: None of the elements called in your JS is there in your HTML markup. How would we know which element is doing what?